# How to onclick open WhatsApp in iPhone or Android with number like +55 (51) 9988-7766

Tags: onclick, whatsapp

How to onclick in some link in page, open WhathsApp in iPhone or Android with number like +55 (51) 9988-7766 to start a conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some test its working for me:

```
<a style="color: #fff;" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=Olá gostaria de mais informações&phone=+555199887766">
   (51) 9988-7766
</a>
```